# Convert text file to dictionary with one key and multiple values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert a text file to dictionary which I'm able to do so using `defaultdict`.

The output is well and expected. But my concern now is how to do further split my values if my format of txt file is not just ":" but also with "," and "(spacing)" ? I tried insert somemore loops in but it didn't work so I removed them.

For example:

```
Cost : 45
Shape: Square, triangle, rectangle
Color:
red
blue
yellow
```

Desired output:

```
{'Cost' ['45']}    
{'Shape' ['Square'], ['triangle'], ['rectangle'] }
{'Color' ['red'], ['blue'], ['yellow']}
```

Here is my current code. How should I modify it?

```
#converting txt file to dictionary with key value pair
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open("t.txt") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        k, v = line.strip().split(":")
        d[k].append(v)
print d
```

Comment: @martin Pieters edited. Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find a line with `:` in it you have a key or else you have values so add the value to the last key `k`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open("test.txt") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if ":" in line:
            k, v = line.rstrip().split(":")
            d[k].extend(map(str.strip,v.split(","))  if v.strip() else [])
        else:
            d[k].append(line.rstrip())
    print(d)
```

Inout:

```
Cost : 45
Shape: Square, triangle, rectangle
Color:
red
blue
yellow
Foo : 1, 2, 3
Bar :
100
200
300
```

Output:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(d)


{'Bar ': ['100', '200', '300'],
'Color': ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'],
'Cost ': ['45'],
'Foo ': ['1', '2', '3'],
'Shape': ['Square', 'triangle', 'rectangle']}
```

You can change the code easily to put each value in an individual list but I would think all the values in one list would make more sense.

Comment: I see! I've tried for hours. You're awesome! Thanks